# A phase diagram outlining

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to solve this differential equation
$$x^{ \prime}=f(x)-nx-y$$ $$y^{\prime}=\frac{(f^{\prime}(x)-r)y}{\alpha}$$ 
where
$f:[0,+\infty[\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is an increasing and concave function such that $f(0)=0$, $\displaystyle\lim _{x \rightarrow  0}f^{\prime}(x)=+\infty$, $\displaystyle\lim _{x \rightarrow  +\infty}f^{\prime}(x)=0$ and $\{ n,r,\alpha\} \subset ]0,1[$.

1. Determine the existence and number of equilibria
2. Draw the phase diagram for the region $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$.

Note: $(0,0)$ is equilibrium, but there is another part of this?

grateful if you give me any suggestions how to solve this problem

Comment: You might want to rename your dependent variables from $k,c$ to $x,y$.  It will be easier for people to read. Thanks

Comment: The function $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ matches the description of your function. From second equation, you can solve for $y(t)$ in terms of $x(t)$: $y(t)=y(0)\exp\left(\frac{(f^{\prime}(x(t))-r)}{\alpha}\right)$

Comment: there any program to draw phase diagram?

Comment: @mike The exponent in the exponential in your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @Did Thanks for spotting the error. It should be $y(t)=y(0)\exp\left(\frac{f(x(t))-r t)}{\alpha}\right)$

Comment: @mike Still incorrect (the derivative of $f(x(t))-rt$ with respect to $t$ is $f'(x(t))x'(t)-r$, not $f'(x(t))-r$).

Comment: @Did Thanks again! $y(t)=y(0)\exp\left((1/\alpha)\int_{1}^{t}(f'(x(s))-r)ds\right)$

Comment: Question 2. has several cases. Unless you specify some values of $n$, $r$, $\alpha$, it seems difficult to answer it. In particular, are you interested in $n/r$ greater or smaller than $2$?

Comment: interested n/r  smaller than 2

Comment: Right. Please explain what you did to solve 1. If $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, you should find two equilibria (none of which being (0,0) since the system is not defined at (0,0)), a saddle point and a stable node.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a complete solution.  I just give you some hints that I will be using if I have to solve this problem.

The equations to determine the equilibrium points are given by:
$$0=x^{ \prime}=f(x)-nx-y......(1)$$
$$0=y^{\prime}=\frac{(f^{\prime}(x)-r)y}{\alpha}......(2)$$

Because $f(0)=0$, we can verify that $x=y=0$ satisfies (1) and (2).

The other solutions of the equilibrium points are given by:
$$0=f(x)-nx-y......(3)$$
$$0=f^{\prime}(x)-r......(4)$$

These equilibrium points are then independent of $\alpha$.

Suppose that the solution to (4) is 
$$x=x_1(r)$$
from (3) we may then get
$$y_1(n,r)=f(x_1(r))+n x_1(r)$$.

To draw phase diagram, we now pick $n=r=\alpha=1/2$ and $f(x)=x^{1/3}$ so that 
$f'(x)=(1/3)x^{-2/3}$.

From (4) we obtain
$$x_1=(2/3)^{-1/2}=0.544$$

and thus from (3) we obtain
$$y_1=f(x_1)+(1/2) x_1=(2/3)^{-1/2}=x_1=0.544$$.

Now you can pick a point $(x(0),y(0))$ with $0 < x(0) <x_1$ and $0 < y(0) <y_1$ as the initial point and use the equations (1) and (2) to calculate the initial velocity $x'(0),y'(0)$ to deduce how the initial point should move.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. You will have some program to plot the case $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$, it can also be $f(x)=ln(x)$ with $n=r=\alpha=0.5$ ?

Comment: @helmonio $\ln(x=0)\not = 0$

Comment: true! I'm lost as to plot the phase diagram for the case $ \sqrt{x} $

Comment: "From (3) we obtain" Sorry but no. (Did you... *differentiate* (3) with respect to $x$ to get this? How is this even *related* to the fixed points of the system?)

Comment: @Did Thanks for spotting the error.  I corrected the formulas.